# C++ :My program won't compile and I am not sure why. I think I am missing a library...? Easy answer

Tags: c++, class, structure

This is not a homework assignment. I was reviewing my basic C++ knowledge for my new coding class and I was messing around with the structs example he gives in one of the slides.
Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct PERSON
{
    string name;
    int age;
};

PERSON get_person(void)
{
    PERSON temp;
    cin >> temp.name;
    cin >>temp.age;
    return(temp);
}

int main(void)
{
    PERSON me;
    me= get_person();
    cout<<me.name;
    cin.get();
}
```

//It won't recognize the ">>" and "<<" and wont compile. I am thinking it is because I am using a struct and did not include something at the beginning of my code.
 Any ideas why?

Comment: put ``#include <string>`` after ``#include <iostream>``

Comment: Wow that did it.
Do you know a source that summarizes what to include when? I actually forgot to include string but it is always hard to remember what to include in which situation.
Oh and thank you!!

Comment: @user - The rule is to always include everything you need. :-)  Like `<string>` if you are using `std::string` or `<vector>` when you use a `std::vector`. Sometimes you get away with not including the proper header, because it might get included indirectly thru some other header, but you cannot rely on this (as you noticed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string` is not a primitive type in C++. `string` is a class, you are creating objects of the class `string` in your code. The `string` ([`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)) class is implemented in the C++ STL (standard template library).

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is the official C++ standard library documentation. You may find information about the headers in the C++ standard library, functions, classes, etc. I recommend not going to cplusplus.com, as it has false documentation in some places.

Also, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header) is a quick link to all headers available in the C++ standard library, with a brief description of each.

EDIT:

To answer the actual question (which I did in the comments): place `#include <string>` after `#include <iostream>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the below statement

```
  #include <string>
```